# How to modify default properties of new WinForm in visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms

I want a new created winform to have a pre-defined Fonts and Icon.

I can do this by manually inherit all new winform to a modified winform (with defined fonts and icon).

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: Do you mean when you add a brand new windows form to your project?

Comment: Create a method which can read through win-form and apply new styles or create custom usercontrol. Have a look at [Implementing your own colour themes in a C# Windows Forms application](http://psycodedeveloper.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/implementing-your-own-colour-themes-in-a-c-windows-forms-application/)

Comment: @roryap yes, by adding a new form, the fonts and icon is set to what i want without changing it manually.

Comment: See [Export Template Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185318(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by modifying the item template.  For example, locate the **Form.zip** file, usually located here (if you're using VS 2010):

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Windows Forms\1033**

Open the zip file, save the **form.designer.cs** file out to a temporary location on your computer, and open it in a text editor.  You will see something like the following:

```
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    partial class $safeitemrootname$
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.Text = "$safeitemrootname$";
            //****** MAKE YOUR DESIRED CHANGES HERE
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Make any necessary changes, for example where I have added the comment `//****** MAKE YOUR DESIRED CHANGES HERE` above.  Save the file, and drop it back into the **Form.zip** file.

Close all instances of Visual Studio, then run the VS cmd prompt by going to **Start > All Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010\Visual Studio Tools\Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)**

Enter **devenv /installvstemplates** in the command window and wait for that command to complete.  You can go back into VS and it should have your changes now when you create a new Form item.